# Change color of only the label for TextField in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, application-design, blackberry-editfield

I am trying to a add a TextField. I am using 
`EditField _textBox = new EditField("Subject", "Some text");` for creating a textbox with label as *Subject*. I want to change the color of only the label(Subject) of the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need a custom field to do this because it is not possible to change the colour of the `EditField`'s label, even if you override `EditField.paint()`.

My suggestion is:

- Create a class (e.g. `CustomEditField`) which extends `HorizontalFieldManager`
- Add 2 fields to this, a `LabelField` for the label and an `EditField` for the editable text
- Override the paint() method for the LabelField to set the colour which you want.

Here's the code:

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.EditField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.HorizontalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;

public class CustomEditField extends HorizontalFieldManager{

    private static final int COLOR = 0x00FF0000; //colour for the label 
    private LabelField labelField; //for the label
    private EditField editField; //for the editable text

    public CustomEditField(String label, String initialValue){

        labelField = new LabelField(label){

            public void paint(Graphics g){

            g.setColor(COLOR);
                super.paint(g);
            }

        };

        editField = new EditField("", initialValue); //set the label text to an empty string

        add(labelField);
        add(editField);     
    }   
}
```

Of course, you're still going to need to add in your methods to set and get the text from your EditField, and any other specific methods which you need from EditField, but as a proof of concept this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can `Override` the `paint()` method and can call the `setColor(int RGB)` method to give the color you want may be this will help

Comment: Won't this change both the label and the text content?  The question is how to change the color of just the label.

Answer (score -2):

```
EditField _textBox = new EditField("Subject","Some text")
{
public void paint(Graphics g) 
{
        getManager().invalidate();
        g.setColor(_color);
        super.paint(g);
}
}
```

Comment: Won't this change both the label and the text content?  The question is how to change the color of just the label.

Comment: Why invalidate the Field's Manager? It is not up to the Field to decide whether its Manager's Fields are invalid

Comment: I don't have the answer, otherwise I would have posted it already.